# Connections Cloud Iframe App - How to reuse current user's authentication?

Tags: cross-domain, ibm-connections, iframe-app

I am building a webpage to be embedded as an Iframe App within Connections Cloud. It is based on the principals from [this tutorial](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Dev%20Guide%20topics#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_Communities_apps_with_the_URL_Widget&content=sdkcontent).

The webpage will be hosted on a server outside (of course) the collabserv.com domain. The purpose of the webpage is to interact (read/write) with Connections Cloud, using the [SBT SDK](https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK), on behalf of the current Connections Cloud user.

The user is already authenticated with Connections Cloud, so I would not like there to be an extra login every time the Iframe App is loaded (making calls to Connections Cloud).

Since my webpage is located outside the Connections Cloud host/domain, it's not possible to reuse the user's existing authentication with the Connections Cloud server (?).

Any suggestions for solutions or workarounds?

BTW, my webpage will be hosted on a Domino server, but ideally there will be no user accounts on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to establish an authenticated connection with Connections Cloud using OAuth2. I more or less followed the OAuth2-steps described by Paul Bastide in [this article](http://bastide.org/2014/05/07/curl-oauth-and-ibm-smartcloud-for-social-business/).

All operations from start to the point where "code" is returned, are handled with XPages, reading QueryString for parameters etc. From that point (starting with "Open a Terminal Window" in the article), I programmed a Managed JavaBean that handles the rest of the OAuth-dribbeling.

When the access_token finally is received in my JavaBean, I use that to build a "Bearer authorization header" for an Apache HttpGet object. I then use the HttpGet object to query the Connections Cloud REST APIs.